# My for loop in python3.0 does not iterate fully?

Tags: python, python-3.x

List of 4 items is given.
I need to iteratively remove an item from the list.
At each iteration I need to show: 
- What is removed
- New list

**I am trying this:**

```
import random
teams=["Tottenham", "Ajax", "Barcelona", "Liverpool"] 
for i in teams:
    t1=random.randint(0, len(teams)-1)
    print(teams[t1])
    teams.remove(teams[t1])
    print(teams)
```

**I am getting this:**

Ajax

['Tottenham', 'Barcelona', 'Liverpool']

Liverpool

['Tottenham', 'Barcelona']

**But should get something like this:**

Ajax

['Tottenham', 'Barcelona', 'Liverpool']

Liverpool

['Tottenham', 'Barcelona']

Tottenham

['Barcelona']

Comment: you are removing items from the list you are iterating over... see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list

Comment: Please use the generic `python` tag on all Python questions.

Answer (score -1):

You can [`shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) the list first, then iterate over it:

```
import random

teams = ["Tottenham", "Ajax", "Barcelona", "Liverpool"]
random.shuffle(teams)

while teams:
    print(teams.pop())
    print(teams)
```

## Output

```
Liverpool
['Ajax', 'Tottenham', 'Barcelona']
Barcelona
['Ajax', 'Tottenham']
Tottenham
['Ajax']
Ajax
[]
```

## Note

To shuffle first reduces the complexity of the loop. It might not be applicable in all situations, but it is an option.